# How to use flow_from_directoey() for sub-directories?

Tags: keras, resnet

My directory looks like:

```
-train->class-1->images
               ->masks
      ->class-2->images
               ->masks
data_generator = ImageDataGenerator()
train_generator = data_generator.flow_from_directory(r'C:\Users\user\project-system\New folder\train\\',target_size=(image_size,image_size),batch_size=batch_size,class_mode='categorical')
```

How do I define ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directoey()? I want to load only masks from class-1 and class-2.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Keras documentation, `flow_from_directory` takes the path to a directory & generates batches of augmented data. The target directory should contain one subdirectory per class.  Any **PNG, JPG, BMP, PPM** or **TIF** images inside each of the subdirectories directory tree will be included in the generator.

So if you want to load Masks only, you should make your folders like:

```
-train_masks ->class-1->masks
             ->class-2->masks

-train_image ->class-1->images
             ->class-2->images
```

Comment: I can't change due to the process, I'm following. So i wrote a piece of program to create another class-1 in a directory and under the class-1 folder, i've stored all the images from mask